# How to turn an object of objects to an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What should I to turn this:

```
{
  "1": {"name": "John", "age": "20"},
  "2": {"name": "Sam", "age": "30"},
  "3": {"name": "Tim", "age": "40"},
  }
```

Into this:

```
[
  {"id": "1", "name": "John", "age": "20"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "Sam", "age": "30"},
  {"id": "3", "name": "Tim", "age": "40"},
]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? Did it go wrong? Did you get error messages? Please update the question with some code that shows an error or issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const obj = {
  "1": { name: "John", age: "20" },
  "2": { name: "Sam", age: "30" },
  "3": { name: "Tim", age: "40" },
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
  return { id: key, ...value };
});

console.log(result);
```

using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const obj = {
  "1": { name: "John", age: "20" },
  "2": { name: "Sam", age: "30" },
  "3": { name: "Tim", age: "40" },
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  return { id: key, ...obj[key] };
});

console.log(result);
```

using [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```js
const obj = {
  "1": { name: "John", age: "20" },
  "2": { name: "Sam", age: "30" },
  "3": { name: "Tim", age: "40" },
};

const result = [];
for (let key in obj) {
  result.push({ id: key, ...obj[key] });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).map(([id, value]) => ({
        id,
        ...value
    }))
}
```